# array_walk and array column for multidimensional form array

Tags: php

I have an array returned from a form as below:

```
[ticket_detail] => Array
        (
            [ticket_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 101
                    [1] => 102
                    [2] => 103
                )

            [price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                    [1] => 20
                    [2] => 30
                )
        )
```

I could extract a single column values using the below code:

```
$arr = array_map(function ($x) {
    return $x[0];
}, $ticket_detail);

Array
(
    [ticket_id] => 101
    [price] => 10
}
```

How do I combine this with array_walk so I can get the below result?

```
[ticket_detail] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ticket_id] => 101
                    [price] => 10
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ticket_id] => 102
                    [price] => 20
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ticket_id] => 103
                    [price] => 30
                )
        )
```

PS: I'm looking for an alternate solution without using a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Always `var_export` your input data instead of `print_r` when pasting your input here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to get your required result.

```
$arr = array_map(function ($ticket_id, $price) {
    return array(
        'ticket_id' => $ticket_id,
        'price' => $price
    );
}, $ticket_detail['ticket_id'], $ticket_detail['price']);

$result = array('ticket_detail' => $arr);
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the way to make it more dynamic

```
$keys = array_keys($ticket_detail['ticket_detail']);
$arrayValues = array_values($ticket_detail['ticket_detail']);

$arr = array_map(function (...$values) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, $values);
}, ...$arrayValues);

$result = array('ticket_detail' => $arr);
```

Comment: Can you convert this to a generic function without explicitly defining the column names (like my single column example) so that it is not restricted to 2 columns (and would still work if I get a new column later without me rewriting the code)?

Comment: @Ravi sure updated with another solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you wish to make this *generic*, you can do the below.

- Get the subarray keys like `ticket_id, price` etc since they need to be attached as keys for each resultant row using `array_keys`.
- Get no. of rows for any individual subarray(*any* because the rows would be symmetric, as in same for every other key).
- Use `array_walk` to walk over these column values one by one. Use them as index in your `array_column` function on your `ticket_detail` array and use `array_combine` to combine the initially retrieved keys(as done in the 1<sup>st</sup> step) with the current row data picked up from each individual subarray and add them to the result.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$keys = array_keys($ticket_detail['ticket_detail']);

$result = ['ticket_detail' => []];
$columns = range(1, count(current($ticket_detail['ticket_detail'])));

array_walk($columns, function($index) use ($ticket_detail, $keys, &$result){
    $result['ticket_detail'][] = array_combine($keys, array_column($ticket_detail['ticket_detail'], $index - 1)); 
});

print_r($result);
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/WZJCE)

Using `array_map`, we can simply return the combined keys and values row for each element.

```
$result['ticket_detail'] = array_map(function($index) use ($ticket_detail, $keys){
    return array_combine($keys, array_column($ticket_detail['ticket_detail'], $index - 1)); 
}, $columns);
```

[**Live Demo**](https://3v4l.org/39Jhl)

Comment: Thank you. Is `array_walk` required or can be done with just `array_map` too?

Comment: @Ravi array_map can be used too but I presume array_walk seems better suited for readability.

Comment: thanks. can you please post the array_map solution too?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ticket_detail = [
  'ticket_detail' => [
    'ticket_id' => [ 101, 102, 103 ],
    'price'     => [ 10, 20, 30 ]
  ]
];

$result = array_map(
  fn($ticket_id, $price) => compact('ticket_id', 'price'),
  $ticket_detail['ticket_detail']['ticket_id'],
  $ticket_detail['ticket_detail']['price']
);
```